# Using Flash memory with STM32C031C6TX

Tags: c, stm32, nucleo

What I am trying to add is after 5 seconds of the LEDs being off, I want to save the last LED color then when I turn the LED back on it is the last color before I previously turned off the LED. What I have read online is that I should use the flash memory with my microcontroller to get the functionality I'm trying to achieve.

The microcontroller I am using is STM32C031C6TX.

I cant seem to get it working properly. This is my current setup:

**Included: #include "stm32c0xx_hal_flash.h" and #define LAST_COLOR_ADDRESS ((uint32_t)0x08000000)**

```
/* Includes ------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#include "main.h"

/* Private includes ----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "stm32c0xx_hal_flash.h"


/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */

/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */

#define LAST_COLOR_ADDRESS ((uint32_t)0x08000000)

/* USER CODE END PD */
```

```
  void switch_off_all_leds(void)
  {

        uint32_t lastColor = ((__HAL_TIM_GET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3) << 16) |
                              (__HAL_TIM_GET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2) << 8) |
                              (__HAL_TIM_GET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4)));

        HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
        FLASH_Erase_Sector(FLASH_SECTOR_0, FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_1); // Erase the sector before programming
        HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, LAST_COLOR_ADDRESS, lastColor);
        HAL_FLASH_Lock();

      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 0); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 0); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 0); // Blue
  };
```

**Full code:**

```
int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();

  SystemClock_Config();

  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3); // Red
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2); // Green
  HAL_TIM_PWM_Start(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4); // Blue

    uint8_t sins[360] = {
        127,129,131,134,136,138,140,143,145,147,149,151,154,156,158,160,162,164,166,169,171,173,175,177,179,181,183,185,187,189,191,193,195,196,198,200,
        202,204,205,207,209,211,212,214,216,217,219,220,222,223,225,226,227,229,230,231,233,234,235,236,237,239,240,241,242,243,243,244,245,246,247,248,
        248,249,250,250,251,251,252,252,253,253,253,254,254,254,254,254,254,254,255,254,254,254,254,254,254,254,253,253,253,252,252,251,251,250,250,249,
        248,248,247,246,245,244,243,243,242,241,240,239,237,236,235,234,233,231,230,229,227,226,225,223,222,220,219,217,216,214,212,211,209,207,205,204,
        202,200,198,196,195,193,191,189,187,185,183,181,179,177,175,173,171,169,166,164,162,160,158,156,154,151,149,147,145,143,140,138,136,134,131,129,
        127,125,123,120,118,116,114,111,109,107,105,103,100,98,96,94,92,90,88,85,83,81,79,77,75,73,71,69,67,65,63,61,59,58,56,54,
        52,50,49,47,45,43,42,40,38,37,35,34,32,31,29,28,27,25,24,23,21,20,19,18,17,15,14,13,12,11,11,10,9,8,7,6,
        6,5,4,4,3,3,2,2,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,
        6,6,7,8,9,10,11,11,12,13,14,15,17,18,19,20,21,23,24,25,27,28,29,31,32,34,35,37,38,40,42,43,45,47,49,50,
        52,54,56,58,59,61,63,65,67,69,71,73,75,77,79,81,83,85,88,90,92,94,96,98,100,103,105,107,109,111,114,116,118,120,123,125
    };

  enum button_state_e {
      BUTTON_NOT_PRESSED,
      BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED,
      BUTTON_PRESSED
  };

  static enum button_state_e button_state = BUTTON_NOT_PRESSED;
  static uint8_t color_sequence = 0;



  void red_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 230); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 0); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 0); // Blue
  };

  void green_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 0); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 230); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 0); // Blue
  };

  void blue_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 0); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 0); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 230); // Blue
  };

  void pink_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 230); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 0); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 50); // Blue
  };

  void teal_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 0); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 230); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 230); // Blue
  };

  void yellow_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 230); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 140); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 0); // Blue
  };

  void orange_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 230); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 25); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 0); // Blue
  };

  void purple_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 230); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 0); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 100); // Blue
  };

  void white_sequence(void) {
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 230); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 230); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 230); // Blue
  };

  void party_sequence(void) {

      int i = 0;

      while (1) {
          for (i = 0; i < 360; i++) {
              __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, sins[i]); // Red
              __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, sins[(i + 120) % 360]); // Green
              __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, sins[(i + 240) % 360]); // Blue

              HAL_Delay(2);

              if (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Toggle_Switch_GPIO_Port, Toggle_Switch_Pin) != GPIO_PIN_SET)
                    return;
          }
      }
  };

  void switch_off_all_leds(void)
  {

        uint32_t lastColor = ((__HAL_TIM_GET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3) << 16) |
                              (__HAL_TIM_GET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2) << 8) |
                              (__HAL_TIM_GET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4)));

        HAL_FLASH_Unlock();
        FLASH_Erase_Sector(FLASH_SECTOR_0, FLASH_VOLTAGE_RANGE_1);
        HAL_FLASH_Program(FLASH_TYPEPROGRAM_WORD, LAST_COLOR_ADDRESS, lastColor);
        HAL_FLASH_Lock();

      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_3, 0); // Red
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_2, 0); // Green
      __HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE(&htim3, TIM_CHANNEL_4, 0); // Blue
  };

  while (1)
  {

     bool pressed = (HAL_GPIO_ReadPin(Toggle_Switch_GPIO_Port, Toggle_Switch_Pin) == GPIO_PIN_SET);

        switch (button_state)
        {
            case BUTTON_NOT_PRESSED:
                if (pressed)
                    button_state = BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED;
                break;

            case BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED:
                if (pressed)
                {
                    button_state = BUTTON_PRESSED;

                    switch (color_sequence) {

                    case 0:
                        red_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        green_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        blue_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        pink_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        teal_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        yellow_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        orange_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        purple_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        white_sequence();
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        party_sequence();
                        break;
                    }

                    color_sequence = (color_sequence + 1) % 10;
                }
                else
                    button_state = BUTTON_NOT_PRESSED;
                break;

            case BUTTON_PRESSED:
                if (!pressed)
                {
                    button_state = BUTTON_NOT_PRESSED;
                    switch_off_all_leds();
                }
                break;
        }

        HAL_Delay(10);

  }
}
```

If I missed any valuable information please let me know and I will provide more.

Thank you!

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to be erasing and writing the flash every time you switch off the LEDs. What is the problem that you want to solve (that your code did not already achieve before you started thinking about flash)? You would use flash if you want to save some state that survives a power cycle. This is not what you describe.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Hello again! So right now the everything works great. I have 9 colors that i cycle through every time i switch the switch on and off. Now i want to add a new feature.
Say i am switching the switch on and off and i stop on color orange then turn the LEDs off. After 5 seconds of being off, then turning the leds back on i want color to be orange instead of it going to the next color.  I want to have a way to save the last color that the LEDs were on, only after 5 seconds of the LEDs being off. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you just want to do this while the MCU is switched on, so you can just use regular variables in RAM to track the current state, you don't need to store anything in non-volatile memory like flash.

Make a new variable to record the current millisecond tick value when the LEDs go off:

```c
uint32_t led_off_tick;

....the code that switches off the LEDs...

    case BUTTON_PRESSED:
        if (!pressed)
        {
            button_state = BUTTON_NOT_PRESSED;
            switch_off_all_leds();
            led_off_tick = HAL_GetTick(); // Record when the LEDs went off
        }
```

Change the "switch on" code to only increment the current colour scheme if the switch on is less than 5 seconds since the last off:

```
    case BUTTON_JUST_PRESSED:
        if (pressed)
        {
             button_state = BUTTON_PRESSED;

             if ((HAL_GetTick() - led_off_tick) < 5000u)
                 color_sequence = (color_sequence + 1) % 10;

             switch (color_sequence) {
             case 0:
                 red_sequence();
                 break;
             ... etc ...
        }
```

and obviously remove the increment of `color_sequence` at the end of that code.

If you really needed to track state over a power-cycle, you might need to use flash, but there are also battery-backed registers you could use (if you have a battery in your system, for the RTC).

Comment: That works great!! I just realized that when i unplug the board from power and plug the board back in it starts back at case 0: as it should but i would like it to save the last color it was at before i removed the power (usb). is that still possible without saving it to memory?

Comment: If you have a battery on your board (for the RTC) then there are registers that survive a power-cycle that you could use. If you don't, you would indeed have to use flash. And that's going to be way more pain than it is worth for your application.

Answer (score -1):

Not much use in telling you your design is misguided like the other answers here.

You're saving the variable to flash, but I don't see anywhere you're pulling it back out. I'd recommend using a tool like STM32CubeProgrammer to check that spot in flash memory to be sure it's being saved there.

You'll want to pull out that section of memory when you go to start the program and use that to set the initial state of the lights.
See the HAL manual for your microcontroller for more details on how to use flash: https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um3029-description-of-stm32c0-hal-and-lowlayer-drivers-stmicroelectronics.pdf

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).